GitHub enterpise Copilot SSO - Unable to login from VS code/Visual studio - language model unavailable
We have enabled SSO from Azure to GitHub Enterprise and it work
Enabled Copilot and it works as well when logging with Azure account.
Also,Copilot works from Web browser.
The problem is, when loging from Visual Studio code Coplilot extension:Specified github-enterprise.uri": "https://company.ghe.com"
When logging in from VS studio,i have option "Sign in with company.ghe.is to use copilot" i'm redirected to https://company.ghe.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=01ab8ac9400c4e429b23&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fvscode.dev%2Fredirect&scope=user%3Aemail&skip_account_picker=true&state=vscode%253A%252F%252Fvscode.github-authentication%252Fdid-authenticate%253Fnonce%253D495ab4233d34f1e%2526windowId%253D1, enter my Azure credentials and page shows:
You are being redirected to the authorized application.
If your browser does not redirect you back, please visit this setup page to continue.
And that page keeps being opened.
When i click that page, i'm redirected to VS code copilot chat, but when i type anything, i'm getting "Language model unavailable"
In Copilot chat extension logs getting Error: Failed to fetch models (7d78754a-e851-4640-8203-f17624accc77): unauthorized: invalid token: cannot validate HMAC
Confirmed no network/firewall issues.
EDIT:
Created case to GithUb enterprise support,sent them VS Code Coplilot trace logs,waiting for reply.
